# Why can't I find the install.rdf and chrome.manifest for this plugin?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

https://github.com/clark800/entropass

I want to make some changes to the firefox version of this open source plugin. However the source doesn't seem to have an install.rdf or a chrome.manifest. What am I supposed to do with it after making modifications to it.

Comment: https://github.com/clark800/entropass/tree/master/chrome/entropass it looks like it has a data and lib folder. This is an addon-sdk addon that hasnt been made with "cfx make" or something. after they do that, then it will have an install.rdf

Comment: Thanks! What about chrome.manifest?

Comment: Yep that will come too after its "compiled"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any need for a `chrome.manifest` and the `install.rdf` will be generated by [cfx](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx) or [jpm](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm) when used in this folder https://github.com/clark800/entropass/tree/master/firefox/entropass